# From the drop-down list by selecting "delete" clearContent(); the cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I have to use the sheet a lot on phone,
but it's quite awkward because it often doesn't show the delete button right away and I have to select it after the three dots
to make this easier, i thought i would add the word delete to the data
if I have already written something into the cell then selecting delete will delete the contents of the cell
the tricky part is that if something is already in the cell and I select Delete then it will write it afterwards so e.g.
write "something" > choose "Delete" than got

something, Delete

so i want a match that finds the word delete anywhere in the cell

my thought is that there should be a if(  .match(/^Delete/) and clearContent(); somewhere for the newvalue and the oldvalue part but i couldn't figure out how to keep the script working like it used to and even find delete cell too

unchanged script:

```
 function onEdit(e) {
          const magicCells = ['B3:U27', 'W3:AP27'];
          const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
          let intersect;
          if (e.value === undefined
            || !e.oldValue
            || !magicCells.some(rangeA1 => (intersect = getRangeIntersection_(e.range, 
            ss.getRange(rangeA1))))) {
            return;
          }
  
  var oldValue;
  var newValue;
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (activeCell.getColumn() > 1) {
    newValue = e.value;
    oldValue = e.oldValue;
   
    if (!e.value) {
      activeCell.setValue("");

    } else {
      if (!e.oldValue) {
        activeCell.setValue(newValue);
       
      } else {
        if (newValue.indexOf(oldValue) < 0) {
          activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ', ' + newValue);

        } else {
          activeCell.setValue(newValue);

        };
      };
    };
  };
}

function getRangeIntersection_(range, intersectingRange) {
      // version 1.4, written by --Hyde, 19 October 2020
      var sheet = range.getSheet();
      if (sheet.getSheetId() !== intersectingRange.getSheet().getSheetId()) {
        return null;
      }
      var rowStart = Math.max(range.getRow(), intersectingRange.getRow());
      var rowEnd = Math.min(range.getLastRow(), intersectingRange.getLastRow());
      if (rowStart > rowEnd) {
        return null;
      }
      var columnStart = Math.max(range.getColumn(), intersectingRange.getColumn());
      var columnEnd = Math.min(range.getLastColumn(), intersectingRange.getLastColumn());
      if (columnStart > columnEnd) {
        return null;
      }
      return {
        sheet: sheet,
        range: sheet.getRange(rowStart, columnStart, rowEnd - rowStart + 1, columnEnd - columnStart + 1),
        rowStart: rowStart,
        columnStart: columnStart,
        rowEnd: rowEnd,
        columnEnd: columnEnd,
        numRows: rowEnd - rowStart + 1,
        numColumns: columnEnd - columnStart + 1,
      };
    }
```

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not quite fully understood your goal. You want to delete the content of the cell (from the range in your code) when you write a "delete" word in the cell?. Can you share a sample sheet to visualize your input data as well. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: const magicCells = ['B3:U27', 'W3:AP27'];
if that's what you mean, it's only to prevent the multi select dropdown menu not working elsewhere

i make a test sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FX_07F1Qu31FW1QOvzFMj4O_fjwilt_pX_Tw9_mFsEw/edit#gid=699332791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can refer to this minimum reproducible sample code:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = e.source;
  var cell = e.range;
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();


  Logger.log(row);
  Logger.log(col);
  Logger.log(cell.getDisplayValue());
  //Check if modified cell is in sheet "dropdown menu delete cell with script - unsolved"
  //Check if modified cell is within range B3:I27
  if(ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "dropdown menu delete cell with script - unsolved"
    && row >= 3 && row <= 27 && col >= 2 && col <= 9){
    if(cell.getDisplayValue().includes('DeleteCell')){
      cell.clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

- I did not check your existing getRangeIntersection_() to check if the modified cell is within the set of ranges you provided.
- I manually checked the row and column index based on your sample sheet
- Use [String.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if a string exist within a string (this is in case sensitive)
- Clear the content of the cell if it has "DeleteCell" in its value

### (UPDATE)

Here is a sample script combined in your existing script (where new data can be appended to the old data if not "DeleteCell" value was selected):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const magicCells = ['B3:U27', 'W3:AP27'];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  if (e.value === undefined
    || !e.oldValue
    || !magicCells.some(rangeA1 => (intersect = getRangeIntersection_(e.range, ss.getRange(rangeA1))))) {
    return;
  }
  
  var oldValue;
  var newValue;
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();

  if (activeCell.getColumn() > 1) {
    newValue = e.value;
    oldValue = e.oldValue;
   
    if (!e.value) {
      activeCell.setValue("");

    } else {
      if (!e.oldValue) {
        activeCell.setValue(newValue);
       
      } else {
        if (newValue.indexOf(oldValue) < 0) {
          if(newValue == 'DeleteCell'){
            activeCell.clearContent();
          }else{
            activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ', ' + newValue);
          }
        } else {
          activeCell.setValue(newValue);
        };
      };
    };
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but for me it just sometimes(70% ), delete the cell contents i see it trying to delete, but what it deleted it brings back again
or did I modify the code you wrote incorrectly? maybe too fast and need a delay?


`function deleteCell(e){
  var ss = e.source;
  var cell = e.range;
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();

  if(ss.getActiveSheet() && row >= 3 && row <= 27 && col >= 2 && col <= 50){
    if(cell.getDisplayValue().includes('DeleteCell')){
      cell.clearContent();
    }
  }
}`

Comment: trying a little further the script you gave me I was able to add it to my script with a little modification but it still blinks twice and then deletes but it's fine : ) I added it to the test sheet in case you didn't understand what I said.Thanks for your help it helped a lot!

Comment: remove this line in your script `activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ', ' + newValue);`.

Comment: but this is the key to my script to be able to add more data/item to one cell
and in between plus I can write manually into the cell

Comment: Updated the answer with more simplified code. I removed unnecessary variables. Let me know if there are still some issues

Comment: perfect:) thank you very much for the modification!